# Extracting data from a text file

Tags: python, string, text-processing

New to Python, and have a very basic question:

I have a text file, which is formatted like the following example (the first number is a date, the second a value assosiated with it):

```
4.12. -11
5.12. 24
6.12. 192
7.12. -34
8.12. 921
```

I need a way to find the 'value' from the text file, for further use. The values can be pretty much anything - as long as they are numbers.

Comment: And of course, the date can be anydate from 1.1. to 31.12.

Comment: go through this http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one vale separated by number of spaces (whitespace characters, to be precise):

```
data = {}

with open('filename') as f:
    for line in f:
        row = line.split()
        data[row[0]] = row[1]
```

Assumptions: the keys in first column are unique.

now you can access `data[value]` to get the value, for example:

```
>>> print data['8.12.']
921
```

If you can have multiple values per key/date, then:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

with open('filename') as f:
    for line in f:
        row = line.split()
        data[row[0]].append(row[1])
```

Now the data will be a dictionary and values will be list of all values found in file. Therefore for file:

```
1.1. 10
2.1. 11
1.1. 12
```

The `data['1.1']` will be `["10", "12"]`

You might have to add conversion of string to number to fully fit your requirements:

```
data[row[0]] = int(row[1])
```

or:

```
data[row[0]] = float(row[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

To loop over line by line in a file, try:

```
with open('filename') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        print line
```

Then, here's an example of getting the value from a string:

```
>>> s = '4.12. -11'
>>> s.rsplit(' ', 1)
['4.12.', '-11'] # two elements
```

Then here's indexing:

```
value = s.rsplit(' ', 1)[1]
# '-11'
```

But that gives a string, so here's conversion to an integer:

```
myval = int(value)
# -11
```

That's the pieces of the jigsaw, and it's not difficult to put those together...

Comment: The split part was what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) should get you started...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
lines = ["4.12. -11",
    "5.12. 24",
    "6.12. 192",
    "7.12. -34",
    "8.12. 921"]

regexp=re.compile("^(?P<day>\d+)\.(?P<month>\d+)\.\s+(?P<val>-*\d+(\.\d+)*)")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for line in lines:
        matcher = regexp.match(line)
        if regexp.match(line):
            print "%s-%s:%s" % (matcher.group("day"), matcher.group("month"), matcher.group("val"))
```